# How to find amount of pooled tokens in Uniswap v3 pool

Tags: uniswap, uniswapv3, liquidity

Given a Uniswap v3 pool: how can I find (using the Uniswap v3 pool contract) the amount of WETH and other coins that are in the pool?

I know in Uniswap v2, you can just call the [getReserves](https://docs.uniswap.org/contracts/v2/reference/smart-contracts/library#getreserves) function.

For example: for [this pool](https://dexscreener.com/ethereum/0xf5a7ae8d465b476e306c8ef764a91b8f119144b4), I want to get "347,132 ZuZu and 0.5189 WETH in pool".

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As per my knowledge, there is no straight-forward approach to get the reserve pool in UniswapV3. However, you can play around using balanceOf function of token contract to get these number as long as you know the pair address. Piece of code the play around is

```
pairAddress = '0xF5a7AE8D465b476e306c8EF764A91b8f119144B4'

wethContract = web3.eth.contract(address=wethAddress, abi=poolAbi)
zuzuContract = web3.eth.contract(address=zuzuAddress, abi=poolAbi)

wethAmount = wethContract.functions.balanceOf(pairAddress).call()
zuzuAmount = zuzuContract.functions.balanceOf(pairAddress).call()

print(wethAmount)
print(zuzuAmount)
```

Hope it helps.